# How to re-create a partition for which I know the old UUID, start location, and size?

Tags: linux, lvm, luks, qubes, testdisk

I have a LUKS encrypted logical volume which is spread across two physical drives. I use the Qubes OS. The first drive is fine. I did a whoopsie with the partition table of the second drive. But the data on that drive seems to be OK. testdisk can find the windows partition and a little LUKS partition which I had. I managed to look into both and they are good.

I *think*, and ChatGPT backs me up (clutching at straws), that there is a single LUKS header for the whole logical volume. I still have that LUKS header, which is on the first drive. On the second drive, in the place where the second part of the encrypted logical volume should start, I have data which looks like encrypted data.

I know the UUID of the second part of the logical volume. I know the location of the data. I know the size. (I'm getting all this from dracut in the boot partition of the first drive.

How can I recreate my needed partition?

I can use testdisk to re-create the other partition (which is Windows, and which shows up in testdisk). But I didn't do it yet. I just backed up the data and the raw data with dd.

Can I just use parted to create the partition on the spot where  I have the data eg:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc mkpart logical 40000000s 42000000s
```

Then set the UUID to be the one I need re-created

tune2fs -U "4bac4411-201a-2a4d-ab0e-2e4a306a5bb2" /dev/sdb1

What is the problem with that? Hopefully this is only writing the partition table, not overwriting my data. Do I need to think about something more, like do I need to delete the partitions that are there already (which are crap set up by the process that went astray and got me here)

Comment: it is not recommended to span drives with LVM as damage to either drive loses data on all drives. And if more than an hour required to recover better to just reinstall & restore from your backups. Was drive gpt or MBR? The LVM is normally in a partition. Note the Windows has a required unformatted partition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition Recovery tools may not find a unformatted partition and if included in the NTFS partition will not recovery Windows correctly.

Comment: If it's one big LUKS container, then the 2nd segment simply doesn't have UUID you could change with tune2fs (ext234 specific), nor would there be any need to set one. Maybe you mean LVM (which has its own PV/VG/LV UUIDs) but it's unclear from your question.